# ETL: Transforming/cleaning excel files

Tags: excel, database, etl

I am working for a start up where they are getting excel files from different companies with customer information. We do not have any ETL tool at present as the work is handled manually to transform the data into required structure and load into CRM system.
My plan is to load these excel files into a database and also replicate CRM into a database and do some fuzzy maping.
Can you please recommend a light weight ETL tool to apply a few rules to clean the data and compare the existing customer data that we have?

Thanks,
mc

Comment: Hi - what is your target database (oracle, Snowflake, Redshift, etc.)? How are you going to (or how could you) connect to your CRM system to extract data from it (direct DB connection, API, etc)?

Comment: Traget database is Redshift and we are using Stitch to sync data from CRM to Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

Getting Excel feeds is certainly very common, and you need a good process for ingesting and validating them, especially since they are often manually created or tweaked, leading to frequent data and formatting issues. Adding insult to injury, Excel has a very fuzzy concept of data types, often throwing spanners in the works.

Where possible, switch your data sources to other formats (JSON, CSV, database extract). This requires upstream work but so does troubleshooting feed issues, so switching to a better format (and [defining the feed well](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataengineering/comments/islrax/elt_cdc_ddl/g5b4ytu?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)!) pays off for both sides fairly quickly.

[Process Incoming Files Example](https://docs.envobi.com/articles/process-incoming-files-example.html) describes a general approach for reliably handling multiple feeds of incoming files, with processing and archiving of successful and failing files. The example uses my company's [actionETL](https://envobi.com) cross-platform .NET ETL library, but I've also used the same approach previously with other ETL tools.

Map out all current and upcoming data sources and destinations, and see which tools are a good fit. [Try before you buy](https://envobi.com/trial) with your actual ETL feeds and requirements. Expect the ETL data integration to be an ongoing project since feeds and requirements never stop changing and growing.

Cheers,
Kristian